# Calculate mean deviation with Splunk

Tags: statistics, splunk, splunk-calculation

I have a list of values in Splunk. I can use this list to calcualte `avg(vals)` and `stdev(vals)`. How do I calculate the mean deviation.

The mean deviation is the average absolute difference between the mean and each value in the list.

`(Sum_x |mean-x|) / N`

Answer (score 1):

The following SPL can be used to calculate the mean deviation of all `value`s.

`| eventstats mean(value) as mean | eval distance=abs(mean-value) | stats avg(distance) as mean_deviation`

For example, this will generate 10 random values and then calculate the mean deviation.

`| makeresults count=10 | eval value=random()%10 | eventstats mean(value) as mean | eval distance=abs(mean-value) | stats avg(distance) as mean_deviation`

`eventstats` is used to calculate the mean all the values, and add this new field to each event. Then, `eval disatnace` is used to calculate the absolute distance away each value is from the mean. The final `stats` is just used to determine the average of this value.

Look here for documentation around `eventstats` https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/SplunkCloud/latest/SearchReference/Eventstats , and a good blog post around the differences between `stats`, `eventstats` and `streamstats` can be found at https://www.splunk.com/en_us/blog/tips-and-tricks/search-command-stats-eventstats-and-streamstats-2.html